# How to increase inner padding of the 'figure' environment?

Tags: spacing, floats

This is my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
Hello, world!
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It renders as such:

[image]

I want larger inner spacing between the text and the border. Moreover, I want it for all `figure` environments, not only this one. How can I do this?

Comment: It seems that the sep is hard coded to be `3pt`. So, one way would be to redefine the command that does the box: `\makeatletter
\def\@BoxSep{3pt}%
\renewcommand\fs@boxed{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@plain \def\@fs@pre{\setbox\@currbox\vbox{\hbadness10000
\moveleft3.4pt\vbox{\advance\hsize by6.8pt \hrule \hbox to\hsize{\vrule\kern\@BoxSep
\vbox{\kern\@BoxSep\box\@currbox\kern\@BoxSep}\kern\@BoxSep\vrule}\hrule}}}% \def\@fs@mid{\kern2pt}%
\def\@fs@post{}\let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse}
\makeatother`, and then you can change that value of `\@BoxSep` as desired.

Comment: @PeterGrill can you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][tbp]{\@float{figure}[#1]\begin{tcolorbox}}{\end{tcolorbox}\end@float}
\makeatother
 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
Hello, world!
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

IIRC, the float package normally puts the caption below the box rather than inside.  This uses `\captionbelow` if that is what you want, and `\caption` inside.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\@belowbox}

\newcommand{\@captionbelow}[2][\empty]% #1 = short caption(optional), #2 = caption
  {\global\setbox\@belowbox=\vbox{\setlength{\hsize}{\normalwidth}%
  \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \caption{#2}
  \else
    \caption[#1]{#2}
  \fi}}

\renewenvironment{figure}[1][tbp]{\@float{figure}[#1]%
  \edef\normalwidth{\the\linewidth}%
  \let\captionbelow=\@captionbelow \begin{tcolorbox}}%
  {\end{tcolorbox}\unvbox\@belowbox\end@float}
\makeatother
 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
Hello, world!
\captionbelow{\blindtext}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

Since no one has provided a serious solution, here is one using a standard `\fbox`.  BTW, this one would make a `\captionabove` easier to implement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\@middlebox}
\newsavebox{\@belowbox}

\newcommand{\@captionbelow}[2][\empty]% #1 = short caption(optional), #2 = caption
  {\global\setbox\@belowbox=\vbox{\setlength{\hsize}{\normalwidth}%
  \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \caption{#2}
  \else
    \caption[#1]{#2}
  \fi}}

\renewenvironment{figure}[1][tbp]{\@float{figure}[#1]%
  \edef\normalwidth{\the\linewidth}%
  \edef\normalfboxsep{\the\fboxsep}%
  \let\captionbelow=\@captionbelow
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1em}% set width of gap
  \begin{lrbox}{\@middlebox}\minipage{\dimexpr \linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{\normalfboxsep}}% restore default value inside minipage
{\endminipage\end{lrbox}%
  \fbox{\usebox\@middlebox}%
  \unvbox\@belowbox\end@float}
\makeatother
 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
Hello, world!
\captionbelow{\blindtext}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `\usepackage{float}\floatstyle{boxed}\restylefloat{figure}` after your code neutralises the effect :(

Comment: Then don't do that!  One of the goals was to avoid loading the (evil) float package.

Comment: The code above doesn't compile: `Undefined control sequence. l.17 \abx@aux@refcontext`

Comment: Maybe it's possible to use `float` (letting it redefine the `figure` environment) and _then_ redefine it again, adding the padding?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was obvious.  (Unless float redefines figure `\AtBeginDocumant`.)   Did the error come from the aux file?   It might go away if you run it again or "Clean Project".  BTW, tcolorbox does a lot more than just add some space, hense the fun part.